# Diagonalization of a matrix given by a finite group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, diagonalization

$\newcommand{\Q}{\Bbb Q}
\newcommand{\N}{\Bbb N}
\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb R}
\newcommand{\Z}{\Bbb Z}
\newcommand{\C}{\Bbb C}
\newcommand{\A}{\Bbb A}
\newcommand{\GL}{\mathrm{GL}}
\newcommand{\Gal}{\mathrm{Gal}}
\newcommand{\matr}[2]{\begin{pmatrix} #1 \\ #2 \end{pmatrix}}
$

Let $G$ be a finite group and $S : G \to \C$ be any map. Define the matrix
$$ M = (S(xy^{-1}))_{x, y \in G} $$

Is it true that $M$ is diagonalizable of $\C$ ? Note: it would be equivalent to take $M' := (S(xy))_{x, y \in G} $.

---

Thoughts:
It is true if $G = \Z / g \Z$ is a cyclic group of order $g>1$, as one can check that for $U := (e^{2 \pi i x y / g})_{1 \leq x, y \leq g}$, we have $MU = UD$ for some diagonal matrix $D$. Moreover, $U$ is invertible (check the SAGE code below).  This was in some paper by Takashi Ono.
Apparently, it also works for some non-abelian groups, but I don't know how to proceed.

---

```
UCF = UniversalCyclotomicField();
for g in range(1, 6):
    U = matrix(UCF, [[E(g)^(x*y) for x in range(g)] for y in range(g)])
    print(g, U.determinant())#, CC(U.determinant()))
    print(U, "\n")
    print(U.inverse(), " ====== \n\n")
```

Comment: I suspect that for the case of $G = \Bbb Z/g\Bbb Z$, this amounts to the observation that [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) are diagonalizable

Comment: No, it is not true unless $G$ is abelian. Such a matrix describes an arbitrary element of the group algebra $\mathbb C\left[G\right]$ of $G$. But such an element can be nilpotent; it doesn't have to be diagonalizable. The Artin-Wedderburn theorem shows that the group algebra $\mathbb C\left[G\right]$ is isomorphic to a product of matrix rings over $\mathbb{C}$; all these matrix rings are $1\times 1$-matrix rings if and only if $G$ is abelian. From this, it is easy to conclude the claim (since a nonzero $1\times 1$-matrix cannot be nilpotent, but in any larger size it can).

Comment: To clarify darij's comment, your matrix is the matrix of the linear transformation given by multiplying the group algebra $\Bbb C[G]$ by the element $\sum S(g)g$, with respect to $G$ as a basis.

Comment: @darijgrinberg : Thank you for your comment. But I am puzzled because the following code on SAGE returns "True":  G = GL(2, GF(2));
def f(x):    return floor(sqrt(7) * list(G).index(x)^2);
M = matrix(QQbar, [[f(x / y) for x in G] for y in G]);
print(M.is_diagonalizable());   [ You can try it on https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ ]

Comment: Of course, for **most** functions $S$, it will be diagonalizable.

Comment: @darijgrinberg : oh I see. Is there any easy sufficient criterion to ensure that some element $A \in \Bbb C[G]$ gives a diagonalizable map?

Comment: [This work](https://web.archive.org/web/20200225202711/http://archiv.ub.uni-marburg.de/diss/z2012/0468/pdf/dhr.pdf) seems relevant.

Comment: There are some criteria. E.g., any element of the center of $\mathbb{C}\left[G\right]$ is diagonalizable (since the center of a matrix ring are the scalar matrices). And yes, Randriamaro's thesis could be very helpful. There are quite a few families of elements of $\mathbb{C}\left[S_n\right]$ that are diagonalizable, each for its own reasons ([a little presentation of mine](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/waterloo2022.pdf), covering only a little piece of the story).

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Cool! Thanks a lot!